# How change type of remark title in amsthm?

Tags: fonts, theorems, amsthm

How can I easily change the typeface of remark titles in `amsthm` without having to define a completely new style using `\newtheoremstyle`.

More precisely, I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}            
\theoremstyle{remark}          % in order to avoid content to be printed in italics
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
```

PS: I have to use `amsthm` because coauthors want to use it. So solutions involving different theorem packages will not be helpful.

Comment: Gonzalo Medina may have a full solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65951/theorem-style-with-name-as-argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a theorem style the "short way" by adding to the `remark` style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\th@newremark{\th@remark\thm@headfont{\bfseries}}
\makeatletter

\theoremstyle{newremark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
Something
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will accept this solution because Gonzalo Medina's answer involves the `etoolbox` package and when working with coauthors it is usually better not load too many fancy packages because in the end nobody knows what all the packages do.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the `\th@remark` command and change the `\itshape` original declaration for `\thm@headfont` to wahtever you need (in my example code I used `\normalfont`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}            
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\th@remark}{\thm@headfont{\itshape}}{\thm@headfont{\normalfont}}{}{}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark} 

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
test
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]