# Problem with abbreviation of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` (LaTeX)

Tags: errors, arrays, multirow

I have had to typeset several block matrixes lately. So I thought of defining abbreviations of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` so as to avoid having to remember the former needs `{*}` and the latter `{r}` and just give the content of the `\multi`-thing and the number(s) of rows and/or columns that content should occupy. I came to this code, showing two possibilities to define the same command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\multi}{moo}
{\IfNoValueTF#3
        {\IfNoValueTF#2
                {\errmessage{Too few arguments}\errhelp{You must specify either the number of columns or that of rows but not neither.}}
                {\multirow{#2}{*}{#1}}}
        {\if#2n
                \multicolumn{#3}{r}{#1}
        \else
                \multicolumn{#3}{r}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#1}}
        \fi}
}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\multirow{#1}{*}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{r}}
\newcommand{\mrc}[3]{\mc{#2}{\mr{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\xmulti}[3][n]{
    \if#1n
        \mc{#2}{#3}
    \else
        \if#2n
            \mr{#1}{#3}
        \else
            \mrc{#1}{#2}{#3}
        \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
%\multi{mapu}[n][3]&\multi{mu}[4]\\
%\multi{gungu}[2][5]
\end{array}$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{mapu}&\multirow{4}{*}{mu} \\
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{gungu}}
\end{array}\right)$$
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\mc{3}{mapu}&\mr{4}{mu}\\
\mrc{2}{5}{gungu}
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\xmulti{3}{mapu}&\xmulti[4]{n}{mu}\\
\xmulti[2][5]{gungu}
\end{array}$$
\end{document}
```

Trouble is, both commands, no matter what, give the same error:

```
Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.43 \xmulti{3}{mapu}
                     &\multi[4]{n}{mu}\\
```

What does it mean, and how do I correct it? Shouldn't those commands both expand to the explicitly typed thing in the middle? Stranger still, `\multi{foo}[bar]` (`bar` being a number) seems to invariably fall into the `\else` branch of the `\if#2n` conditional, since commenting the instruction there solves the problem, with a `NValue` or the likes being typesetted, whereas it should fall into the `true` value of the `\IfNoValueTF#3` conditional and the `false` branch of the therein nested `\IfNoValueTF#2` conditional. The same (with due changes to the conditionals) goes for `\xmulti{bar}{foo}`, with `bar` a number. Why does that happen?

**Update:**
I've worked on the code, turning it into:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\multi}{omm}
{\IfNoValueTF#2
        {\IfNoValueTF#1
                {\errmessage{Too few arguments}\errhelp{You must specify either the number of columns or that of rows but not neither.}}
                {\multirow{#1}{*}{#3}}}
        {\if#1n
                \multicolumn{#2}{r}{#3}
        \else
                \multicolumn{#2}{r}{\multirow{#1}{*}{#3}}
        \fi}
}
```

That works. Only of course it never falls into the `\IfNoValueTF#2` branch, since `#2` is mandatory. So I tried changing the conditional, getting to:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\multi}{omm}
{\if#2n
        {\IfNoValueTF#1
                {\errmessage{Too few arguments}\errhelp{You must specify either the number of columns or that of rows but not neither.}}
                {\multirow{#1}{*}{#3}}}
\else
        {\if#1n
                \multicolumn{#2}{r}{#3}
        \else
                \multicolumn{#2}{r}{\multirow{#1}{*}{#3}}
        \fi}
\fi}
```

And suddenly I'm back with the `misplaced \omit`. Why?

Comment: No, you can't use `\NewDocumentCommand` for defining an abbreviation of `\multicolumn`. I'm pretty sure this has already been discussed. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17133) for example; you can use an optional argument, but only in the first position with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`

Comment: In addition to egreg's comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @egreg I have updated the question. Why can I use an optional argument only in the first position?

Comment: @MickG It's a limitation of `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`, but you can use `{oom}` as argument specifier; the important thing is that a mandatory argument comes last.

Comment: @egreg OK that works. Could you take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167593/special-theorem-command-tex? It hasn't been answered in 5 days now, so I'm starting to think no-one has seen it. Thanks.

Comment: @MickG I saw it, but I'm not going to answer it.

Comment: Why? And in the answer to this question, what are `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`?

Comment: @MickG If you search a little… http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/what-do-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff-do

Answer (score 3):

You must use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\multi}{oom}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     {
      \errmessage{Too few arguments}
      \errhelp{You must specify either the number of columns or that of rows but not neither.}
     }
     {
      \multirow{#1}{*}{#3}
     }
   }
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{n}
     {
      \multicolumn{#2}{r}{#3}
     }
     {
      \multicolumn{#2}{r}{\multirow{#1}{*}{#3}}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\multi[n][3]{mapu}&\multi[4]{mu}\\
1 & 2 & 3 & \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \\
\multi[2][5]{gungu} & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
&&&&&6 & 7 & 8 \\
&&&&&6 & 7 & 8 \\
&&&&&6 & 7 & 8 \\
&&&&&6 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I believe you're wasting your time trying to make catch-all commands that are more difficult to use than the original ones.

Comment: I'm surprised that _you_ are willing to give an answer for a `\multirow` question ;)

Comment: @Manuel thanks for the link. So they are for `\str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{n}`, which answers point 2 of the other question I linked. @egreg why do you say they are «more difficult to use than the original ones"? I think they are easier in fact, because one doesn't need to remember that `\multicolumn` goes before `\multirow`, that the former requires `{<col num>}{r}` and the latter `{<row num>}{*}`, three things that have caused me quite a few typesetting errors lately. And @tohecz why are you so surprised?