# Fixing overfull `\vbox`

Tags: warnings

With the code:

```
$$A=\msq{\mat{ccccc}
2 & -1 & & \multi[2][2]{\Huge{$0$}} \\
-1& 2 & -1 \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\multi[2][2]{\Huge{$0$}} & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & & -1 & 2
\emat}.$$
```

I get:

```
Overfull \vbox (6.0pt too high) detected at line 45

Overfull \vbox (6.0pt too high) detected at line 45
```

where the code ends at line 45. How can I fix that?

NB `\multi` is as in [Problem with abbreviation of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` (LaTeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168434/problem-with-abbreviation-of-multirow-and-multicolumn-latex), `\msq` is `\msq{#1}=\left[\!\!\!\!#1\!\!\!\!\right]` and `\mat=\begin{array}`, `\emat=end{array}`.

Comment: Is this at the bottom of the page? What is `\multi` and `\emat`? Have you seen [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)? Instead of a code snippet like this, it is *always* better provide full, compilable code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Please, make a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The code snippet does not even make clear, whether plain TeX or LaTeX is used: `$$` should *not* be used in LaTeX, thus it might be plain TeX. `\Huge` might be a hint for LaTeX. `\msq`, `\mat#1#2\emat`, `\multi[#1][#2]#3` seem to be private macros. A MWE clarifies all these issues.

Comment: I can only conjecture that the problem is in what `\multi[2][2]{\Huge{$0$}}` does. Probably a fixed height vertical box, which a `\Huge` zero can't fit in. Use `\huge` or a smaller size.

Comment: I'm using LaTeX. As for the rest, see the edit. And I just can't get used to `\[\]` instead of `$$`. I have seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to many times, but 1) I can't get used to the change because `$$` is automatic and I need speed typing in notes, and 2) it seems from that question that the difference is seen only in a few rare cases and is rarely any big issue, correct me if I'm wrong, so I don't see why I should change.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reduce the size: the `\Huge{$0$}` has to fill a `2x2` block and it's just the right size as `\Huge`; in fact, if anything I'd make it bigger. Could I use `\vbox to …` to solve this in any way?

Comment: you might try `\smash{\Huge{$0$}}` to make the "apparent" height and depth zero.  you might have to fiddle with the vertical position.  (sorry; this is unchecked, so it might not really work as i expect.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes it works and yes I have to fiddle with the position, which is no big deal since I was anyway already doing it both vertically and horizontally, so perfect solution :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `\smash{\Huge $0$}` to make the "apparent" height and depth zero.

you might have to fiddle with the vertical position.

sorry i can't show output, but i'm on the road without any tex resources to test.