# Customizing list of theorems

Tags: theorems, thmtools

Is it possible to avoid brackets surrounding the name of a theorem in the `\listoftheorems` from package `thmtools`? And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: I've already edited this once, so won't again, but there is no need to have 'LaTeX' in the title here: the 'standing assumption' on the site is that we assume LaTeX without other evidence, and in any case have tags such as [tag:plain-tex] and [tag:context] for other formats.

Comment: An example? I don't think `\listoftheorems` does this by default.

Comment: It does @egreg, but only around the `[name=` part. In fact, this question is the leftover of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167593/special-theorem-command/168535#168535 after a bit of research and a few other questions.

Comment: I've taken a look at the `thmtools` documentation and in particular at its implementation. The problem lies in the `\thmtformatoptarg` command, defined with them. It appears that the only solution is manually.redefining that command or changing the `thmtools` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redefine the `\thmtformatoptarg` command.
Because the `thmtools` kept ignoring my redefinitions, I copied the `thm-listof.sty` file to the current directory.  I changed

```
\providecommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{ (#1)}
```

into

```
\providecommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1}
```

to remove the parentheses around the theorem's name.
If you additionally want to remove 'Theorem' (or whatever) from your list of theorems, you could change the definition of `\thmt@mklistcmd` and remove `\thmt@thmname` from the definition.

Comment: Changing style files is not recommended. Better adding `\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg[1]{ #1}` to the document preamble.