# thmname not getting replaced in subfile when loaded from mainfile

Tags: amsmath, subfiles

I have a theorem-style defined like this (based on this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65955/228413):

```
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
    {10pt}%             space above
    {10pt}%             space below
    {}%                 body font
    {}%                 indent amount
    {}%                 theorem head font
    {}%                 punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}%         space after theorem head
    {\underline{\thmname{\@ifempty{#3}{#1}\@ifnotempty{#3}{#3}}}} % theorem head spec

....

\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem*{note}{Notiz}
```

And when using this environment in a subfile it produces the correct result when compiled by itself:

```
\begin{note}[Title]
    \lipsum[4][1-3]
\end{note}
```

[image: title getting displayed correctly as "Title"]

But when the same file is included (`\subfile{file_name}`), the result looks like this:

[image: title getting displayed as "ifemptyTitleNotizifnotemptyTitleTitle"]

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the `\newtheoremstyle` definition between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\makeatletter % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newtheoremstyle{note}% name
    {10pt}%             space above
    {10pt}%             space below
    {}%                 body font
    {}%                 indent amount
    {}%                 theorem head font
    {}%                 punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline}%         space after theorem head
    {\underline{\thmname{\@ifempty{#3}{#1}\@ifnotempty{#3}{#3}}}} % theorem head spec
\makeatother % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Your problem is not related to the `subiles` package. (Well, it is surprising that it works at all when compiling the subfile.)
Check out the source where you copied the code from. There you will also find these two extra commands.

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to do this for all ```\newtheormstyle```?

Comment: You have to do it whenever the character "@" ("at" symbol) appears in a command name. In a `sty` and `cls` file, this character counts as a letter, but on user level it does not. `\makeatletter` makes "at" a letter, and `\makeatother` makes "at" again a character of category "other", as it should be on user level. See also [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6240/110998)